# Why does hydrochloric acid not damage the human stomach?

Tags: acid-base, chemical-biology

Hydrochloric acid ($\ce{HCl}$) is found in the stomach, so why it doesn't damage the stomach despite that it is considered to be one of the most dangerous acids?

Comment: Short answer: the stomach has a lining and is constantly renewing it.

Comment: Of course it does. How do you think stomach ulcer and gastritis come about? (Sure, there are other reasons and counter-reasons.)

Comment: This question already has an answer here on Bio.SE: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/how-does-hcl-not-burn-our-stomach

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not fundamentally about chemistry.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question, because it *does* address chemistry, even though it is chemistry in living species.